# как избежать этой ошибки 'StringReader' не содержит конструктор, который принимает аргументы 2"?

Tags: c#

[image: А вот участок кода где есть 2 ошибки.]

Что за ошибки? На 25 строке "'StringReader' не содержит конструктор, который принимает аргументы 2".    и на 26 "Не удается преобразовать группу методов "ReadToEnd" в тип, не являющийся делегатом "string". Предполагалось вызывать этот метод?". Можете поподробнее рассказать о появление этих ошибок и как их избежать?

Comment: что касается второй ошибки, чтобы вызвать метод нужно поставить круглые скобки

Comment: по поводу первой где вы нашли информацию о таком конструкторе?

Comment: я думаю, что вам вообще StringReader не нужен

Comment: StringReader и StreamReader - это разные классы. Первый читает строку, второй - стрим, с возможностью указать кодировку

Answer (score 0):

Как видно [тут](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.io.stringreader.stringreader(v=vs.110).aspx) конструктор `StringReader` принимает только 1 аргумент `String`, так что `Encoding.Unicode` нужно убрать. А в 26 строчке надо написать `string content_f = reader_f.ReadToEnd()`.

Comment: Я щас попробовал без кодировки и в итоге пишет то что "Аргумент 1: не удается преобразовать из "System.IO.FileStream" в "string" ".

Comment: @GeVaMain все правильно. `StringReader` считывает данные из строки, а не из файла.

Comment: А какой тогда нужно использовать класс(если я правильно понял что дело в нем)?

Comment: А не все понял спасибо.

Comment: Как сказал @PashaPash `StreamReader`